# Real-valued equivalent conditions for positive semi-definite complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, positive-definite

The title is pretty self explanatory, so let me tell you what I know and what I don't:

Let $G \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ be a positive semi-definite complex matrix. It must be hermitian, $G = G^H$, thus we for any $x \in \mathbb{C}^{d}$ we have

$$x^{H} G x = x^{T} G^{T} x^{*} = (x^{H}G^{H}x)^{*} = (x^{H}Gx)^{*}$$
which means $x^{H} G x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So, $G = G^{H}$ condition ensures that $\forall x \in \mathbb{C}^{d}, x^{H} G x \in \mathbb{R}$. What does this mean in terms of real matrices?
Let's write $$G = G_{I} + j G_{Q}$$ where $G_{I}, G_{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. $G = G^{H}$ means that $$G_{I} = G_{I}^{T}$$ and $$G_{Q} = -G_{Q}^{T}$$ but this is not the end. We haven't found additional conditions to make sure that $x^{H} G x$ is positive. Let's write $$x = x_{I}+j x_{Q}$$ where $x_{I}, x_{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$, now I want to find additional real-valued constraints for $x^{H} G x \geq 0$.
$$x^{H} G x \geq 0 \\ (x_{I}^{T}-j x_{Q}^{T}) (G_{I} + j G_{Q}) (x_{I}+j x_{Q}) \geq 0.$$ Writing out the real part (we already know the imaginary part is zero), we have
$$x_I^{T}G_I x_I + x_Q^{T}G_Ix_Q - x_I^{T}G_Q x_Q + x_Q^{T}G_Q x_I \geq 0$$

Setting $x_I$ or $x_Q$ to zero, we deduce that $G_I \succeq 0$. So, the first two terms are always non-negative. We also know that $G_{I} = -G_{I}^{T}$, thus
$$x_Q^{T}G_Q x_I = x_I^{T}G_Q^{T} x_Q = -x_I^{T}G_Q x_Q$$, and I'm stuck with 
$$x_I^{T}G_I x_I + x_Q^{T}G_Ix_Q - 2x_I^{T}G_Q x_Q \geq 0$$
condition which I don't know how to impose on $G_I$ and $G_Q$. (This oddly reminds me of Cauchy-Shwartz inequality!)

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else who has the same question:
I could have written the real condition as a quadratic form in $[x_I, x_Q]$ composite variable and this leads to $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} G_I & -G_Q \\ G_Q & G_I\end{array} \right] \succeq 0$.